# Style in HeaderColumn in Datagrid

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0, silverlight-3.0

Please see this following image of my datagird.

[image]
Now want a border in headerColumn. I have tried columnheader style but it did not work for me.
I want following style of header of datagrid.Please see the following image.
[image]
How can i achieve this style in datagird.
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You have to change the DataGrid template, not columnheader. In the default DataGrid template there is:

```
<sdk:DataGridColumnHeadersPresenter x:Name="ColumnHeadersPresenter" Grid.Column="1"/>
```

I think you have to edit over there.

Comment: Can you please give me more detail? In xaml, Where I have to write this line.

Comment: This line is inside the Datagrid template. You have to customize around it (you could set a border). If you're using Expression Blend, open the Datagrid xaml. In the design mode, press right button on Datagrid and select Edit template > Edit current. It will appear the Template of your datagrid.

Comment: Thanks for reply but it is not working for me.So I have used datagrid Columnheader style instead of sdk:DataGridColumnHeadersPresenter.