# DataGrid Header Style in Silverlight 4.0

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0, silverlight-3.0, silverlight-5.0

**I want to set header of datagrid like following link.**

[Style in HeaderColumn in Datagrid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12420886/style-in-headercolumn-in-datagrid)

**I have used DataGridColumnHeadersPresenter in my code.**

**See my following code:**

```
   <Style x:Key="XYZ" TargetType="sdk:DataGridColumnHeadersPresenter" >
         <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="sdk:DataGridRowGroupHeader">
                    <Border x:Name="ButtonBorder" 
                        CornerRadius="0,0,0,0" 
                        BorderThickness="0"  
                        BorderBrush="Transparent">
                        <Border.Background>
                            <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="1">
                                <GradientBrush.GradientStops>
                                    <GradientStopCollection>
                                        <GradientStop Color="#555" Offset="0.0"/>
                                        <GradientStop Color="#000" Offset="0.8"/>
                                    </GradientStopCollection>
                                </GradientBrush.GradientStops>
                            </LinearGradientBrush>
                        </Border.Background>
                        <ItemsPresenter/>
                    </Border>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
    <Style x:Key="BreakGridStyle" TargetType="sdk:Datagird">
        <Setter Property="HeadersVisibility" Value="Column" />
        <Setter Property="AutoGenerateColumns" Value="False" />
        <Setter Property="Width" Value="Auto" />           
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="sdk:DataGrid">
                    <Grid>
                        <StackPanel>
                            <sdk:DataGridColumnHeadersPresenter Name="ABC" Style="{StaticResource XYZ}" />
                            <ItemsPresenter/>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

**But i got following Error:**

The property '**Template**' was not found in type **'System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.DataGridColumnHeadersPresenter'.**

How to solve this and how to achieve my datagrid's column style as in above link

Comment: In the `BreakGridStyle` your `TargetType` is set to `sdk:Datagird`. Is this a typo only here on SO or do you have it in your code as well?

Comment: In Silverlight, the `DataGridColumnHeadersPresenter` does not support the `Template` property; that is why you get the error message. See [MSDN docs for SL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.datagridcolumnheaderspresenter_properties&#40;v=vs.95&#41;.aspx).

Comment: Thank you for replying.If DataGridColumnHeadersPresenter does not support Template so is it any another way to get column header style as per above link?

Comment: If you only want the look, and don't require the additional functionality of a DataGrid, you can accomplish this easily with a HeaderedItemsControl instead.